# split in lines and take a pattern in a file

Tags: unix, sed, do-while

I have many files .txt which looks like:

file1.txt

```
header
1_fff_aaa 1_rrr_aaa 1_ggg_aaa ...
```

file2.txt

```
header
1_ttt_aaa 1_iii_aaa 1_lll_aaa ...
```

I would like to remove the header and split the string of the second line in multiple lines after the white space and take the pattern in between the _ character:

Output:

```
file1_v1.txt

fff
rrr
ggg

file2_v1.txt

ttt
iii
lll
```

I would like to utilise unix commands like sed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that:

Program: `split.awk`

```
NR == 1 {
    # ignore first header line
    next
}
{
    i=1
    while (i <= NF) {
        gsub(/^[^_]*_/, "", $i)
        gsub(/_[^_]*$/, "", $i)
        print $i
        i++
    }
}
```

Executed like that:

```bash
awk -f split.awk file1.txt > file1_v1.txt
```

To execute it on many files:

```bash
for f in file*.txt; do echo "$f"; awk -f split.awk "$f" > "${f%.txt}_v1.txt" ; done
```

## UPDATE

You could also use `sed` & `tr`:

```bash
sed -n '2,$p' file1.txt | tr " " "\n" | sed 's/^[^_]*_\(.*\)_[^_]*$/\1/'
```

Comment: `NR == 1 { next } { foo }` = `NR > 1 { foo }`. You don't need `gsub()` when a regexp is anchored to the start or end of the string, just `sub()` since it can only match once. You could do `gsub(/^[^_]*_|_[^_]*$/,"",$i)` rather than 2 separate `sub()`s in a POSIX awk though. `i=1; while (i <= NF) { foo; i++ }` is more commonly written `for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { foo }`.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't normally answer a question where the OP hasn't shown any attempt to solve their problem themselves, but since there are multiple answers already...

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="_" }
FNR == 1 {
    close(out)
    out = FILENAME
    sub(/\.txt$/,"_v1&",out)
    next
}
{
    for ( i=2; i<=NF; i+=2 ) {
        print $i > out
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file{1,2}.txt
```

```
$ head file{1,2}_v1.txt
==> file1_v1.txt <==
fff
rrr
ggg

==> file2_v1.txt <==
ttt
iii
lll
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '1d;s/\s\+/\n/g;s/^[^_]*_//mg;s/_.*//mg' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

Use the command line option `-i` to replace inline.

Delete the first line of each file (remove the header).

Replace white space(s) to newlines. This will convert each token to a separate line.

Remove the first part of the string upto and including the first `_` for all lines in the pattern space.

Remove from the first `_` to the end of the line, leaving the result.

N.B. The `-i` option may be replaced by the `-s` option if the user only requires output to stdout from one or more files. Also notice the `m` flag on the last two substitution commands which changes the usual replacement so as to benefit multiline patterns.

To change the output file names, employ GNU parallel:

```
parallel --plus "sed '1d;y/ /\n/;s/^[^_]*_//mg;s/_.*//mg' {} > {.}_v1.{+.}" ::: file1.txt file2.txt ...
```